# listview item having scattered alignment at runtime

Tags: listview, layoutparams

i have a listview item which is being populated at runtime and at the same time the alignment is being determined at runtime. its a chat interface. if message author is friend then the alignment should be left and if message author is me, then the alignment should be right.

but on running it, its just as if the alignment is being done at random irrespective of the message author.
what i have tried:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

i will gladly appreciate any help on this